# How to execute a file written in C from python while passing it string values and accepting/storing the string it returns as output.(Linux)

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, subprocess

I have tried the subprocess module but providing the main function of C with string values but it doesn't seem to work for me. There are certain solutions available on the web but I'm having difficulty in understanding and implementing them. Any help will be appreciated.

I want to execute a file written in C passing it arguments from my pyhthon code and after that C file is executed I want to capture what it returns in my python code.

```
const char* main(int argc , char* argv[]) 
{ 
    printf("Hello World from C \n"); 
    printf("1st string passed is %s \n ",argv[1]);
    printf("2nd string passed is %s \n ", argv[2]);
    char b[] = "success";
    return b; 
}
```

This is the code in C from where I wish to return a string to the python code.

```
import subprocess 
import os 

def excuteC(): 

    s = subprocess.call("./Cvishad hello you;", shell = True)
    print("status is "+ str(s))


if __name__=="__main__": 
    excuteC()
```

This is the code in python where I am calling the C code. It seems to work but I think it is returning a pointer/address but not the actual string "success" that I want. 
The output I get is something like this -

```
Hello World from C
1st string passed is hello 
2nd string passed is you 
status is 80
```

I'm trying out things for the first time in C, so kindly excuse the silly mistakes.

Comment: Please post exactly what you tried and explain in detail what you mean by "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: I hope it is clearer now. @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Did you compile the C code with warnings enabled? A `main()` returning a `char const*` should produce a warning. In any case, you return a pointer to an array that is local to the function, which is bad in and of itself. Concerning your question, passing strings to the C code seems to work, right? In that case, that part could be removed completely to get closer to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your C program is returning a pointer to a string as the process return value, and it gets truncated to an unsigned byte (which you're seeing as e.g. 80).

You can transfer arbitrary data between processes by e.g. (and I'm sure I'm forgetting something)

- sockets
- files
- streams (stdout/stderr; `subprocess.check_output()` in Python)
- shared memory